# Is the "cyclotomic diagonalization" always squarefree?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization, cyclotomic-polynomials

For every integer $n\ge 2$ , define $$f(n):=\Phi_n(n)$$ where $\Phi(n)$ is the $n$ th cyclotomic polynomial. This can be considered as the "cyclotomic diagonalization"

> Prove or disprove the conjecture that $f(n)$ is squarefree for every integer $n\ge 2$

The partial factorizations I determined with PARI/GP (usually, the factors upto $12-13$ digits are found) gave no exponent greater than $1$ upto $n=200$. A rigorous test upto $n=46$ revealed that upto this limit there are only squarefree values.

If it cannot be proven, a good heuristic would also be welcome.

Comment: The numbers are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A070518/b070518.txt

Comment: The bounty is in the spirit of [the Pearl Dive project](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102837/pearl-dive). I will also mention this in MathOverflow in case somebody there sees something.

Comment: All, there exists [a chatroom dedicated to this question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118511/the-diagonalization-of-the-cyclotomic-polynomials). Check it out for some explicit factorizations.

Comment: The conjecture is false ! For $n=28341$ , $p=283411$ , we have $p^2\mid \Phi_n(n)$.

Comment: Upto $p= 2\cdot 10^8$, there is no further counterexample. If $n$ is prime, then upto $p=10^9$ , there is no further counterexample.

Comment: No further counterexamples for $p < 5 \cdot 10^{10}$.

Comment: $p^2 \mid \Phi_n(n)$. No further counterexamples for $p < 2 \cdot 10^{11}$.

Comment: Great, Martin ! Thank you very much !

Comment: @ Peter, an honor for me to complete such a deep search. But not deep enough to uncover more counterexamples. Time will tell when we have better equipment one day.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We want to show that the problem is equivalent to

*For any number $n$ and any prime $q \mid n^n-1$, then $ord_{q^2}(n) \neq n$*

We will see at the end why we expect this to be false, but also that counterexamples are very rare and are likely to have more than forty digits.

Recall the [Moebius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula) defined here, and the notation $v_p(k)$ for the maximum exponent $\alpha$ such that $p^{\alpha} \mid k$. Notice that $v_p(xy) = v_p(x)+v_p(y)$ behaves like a logarithm. The key observation is the following:

**Lemma.** It holds
$$ (**) \ \ \ \ v_p(\Phi_n(n) ) = \sum_{d \mid n} \mu \left (\frac{n}{d} \right ) v_p(n^d-1) $$

*Proof.* It is well known that

$$ \prod_{ d \mid n} \Phi_d(x) = x^n -1 $$

Now for any natural number $x$, taking $v_p$ yields

$$ \sum_{d \mid n} v_p \Phi_d(x) = v_p(x^n-1) $$

Applying the Moebius Inversion Formula we get
$$ v_p \Phi_n(x) = \sum_{d \mid n} \mu \left ( \frac{n}{d} \right ) v_p(x^d-1)$$
and the thesis follow by specializing at $x=n$.

**Main Proof.** Now that we have a formula for the exponent, let's compute it. Set $r:= ord_p(n)$. Note that if $r$ does not divide $n$, it does not divide any of its divisors $d \mid n$; it follows that $n^d \neq 1 \pmod{p}$ for all $d$. Thus equation (**) yields $v_p(\Phi_n(n) ) = 0$. Let us suppose for the rest that $r \mid n$ and set $n'=n/r$.

**Case 1.** $n'=1$, that is $ord_p(n) = n$. In this case the only summand that contributes to the summation in (**) is $v_p(n^n-1)$. This is $\le 1$ if and only if $p^2 \nmid n^n - 1$. Note that $n = ord_p(n) \mid ord_{p^2}(n) $:

- If the $ord_{p^2}(n)$ is equal to $n$, then $p^2 \mid n^n -1 $ and we found a counterexample;
- If instead $ord_{p^2}(n)>n$, we must have that $n^n \neq 1 \pmod{p^2}$ and we are happy.

**Case 2** $n' >1$. This part can seem heavy, but if you are familiar with Moebius Function you will recognize that this is just ordinary Yoga.

The summands that contribute to (**) are all the $d$ that are divisible by $r$. Note that any number $d$ such that $r \mid d \mid n$ can be written as $rd'$, where $d' \mid n'=n/r $. With this observation in mind we write

$$ v_p(\Phi_n(n) ) = \sum_{r \mid d \mid n} \mu \left (\frac{n}{d} \right ) v_p(n^d-1) = 
\sum_{d' \mid n'} \mu \left (\frac{r n'}{r d'} \right ) v_p(n^{rd'}-1) = \sum_{d' \mid n'} \mu \left (\frac{n'}{d'} \right ) v_p((n^r)^{d'}-1)
$$

Now we use the Lifting The Exponent Lemma to split the $v_p$ factor. We get
$$ \sum_{d' \mid n'} \mu \left (\frac{n'}{d'} \right )( v_p(n^r-1) + v_p(d') )= v_p(n^r-1) \sum_{d' \mid n'} \mu \left (\frac{n'}{d'} \right ) + \sum_{d' \mid n'} \mu \left (\frac{n'}{d'} \right ) v_p(d') $$

Since $n'>1$, the first summand is zero: indeed $\sum_{k \mid h} \mu(h/k) = 0$ for $h> 1$. The second factor is more interesting. Suppose $n'= p^{\alpha} m$ with $(m,p) =1$. Every divisor of $n'$ will uniquely write as $p^{\beta} m'$, where $\beta \le \alpha$ and $m' \mid m$. Using the fact that $\mu(ab) = \mu(a)\mu(b)$ for $a,b$ coprimes we get

$$\sum_{d' \mid n'} \mu \left (\frac{n'}{d'} \right ) v_p(d') = \sum_{\beta=0}^{\alpha} \sum_{m' \mid m} \mu(p^{\alpha-\beta}) \mu(m/m') \beta = \sum_{\beta= 0}^{\alpha} \mu(p^{\alpha-\beta})\beta \sum_{m' \mid m} \mu(m/m')$$

We have to do a little distinction here. If $m>1$ this is zero again by the "summation moebius" property. If $m=1$, we are basically saying that $n'=p^{\alpha}$. In this case the formula reduce to

$$ \sum_{\beta=0}^{\alpha} \mu(p^{\alpha-\beta}) \beta = \beta - (\beta-1) = 1$$

And... Voilà!

**Heuristics.** We want to show that it is almost certain that a counterexample exist, but it is very likely to have hundreds of digits. Define for $d \mid p(p-1)$:
$$ X(p) = \{ 1 \le z \le p^2: \ \ (z,p) =1 \} $$
$$ X_d(p) := \{1 \le z \le p^2 : \ \ (z,p) = 1 \text{ and } ord_{p^2}(z) = d \} $$
Note that
$$\# X(p) = \phi(p^2) = p(p-1) \ \ \ \ \#X_d(p) = \#\{\text{roots of } x^d-1 \text{ in } \mathbb{F}_p\} = d$$
It is reasonable to assume that $X_d(p)$ is a random set in $X(p)$; indeed, if I am not wrong, there are some results of Davenport, Erdos, Vinogradov showing that quadratic residues, cubic residues ecc. are equidistributed among $X(p)$, and you can say that $ord_{p^2}(z) = k$ if and only if $z$ is a $\phi(p)/k$ residue but not a $\phi(p)/kq$ residue for all $q \mid \phi(p)/k$. However, I am not expert enough to produce a real proof.

We say that *$p$ is a counterexample to the cdp (cyclotomic diagonalization problem)* if $p^2$ appears as a factor of some $\Phi_n(n)$. We have shown above that this can happen iff $ord_{p^2}(n) = n$. Note that such an $n$ should be a divisor of $\phi(p) = p(p-1)$, because $n = ord_{p^2}(n) \mid p(p-1)$ and must be also coprime with $p$ (otherwise $p \nmid n^n-1$). On balance, the $n$ that make $p$ a counterexample to the cdp must be searched among the divisors of $(p-1)$.

For any such divisor $b$, we must hope that $b \in X_b(p)$. Since $X_b(p)$ is a random set in $X(p)$, this happens with probability $\frac{b}{p(p-1)}$. So the probability that this does not happen for any divisor $b$ is

$$ \prod_{b \mid (p-1) } \left ( 1- \frac{b}{p(p-1)} \right ) $$
The logarithm of this sum can be estimated as
$$ - \sum_{b \mid (p-1) } \frac{b}{p(p-1)} = - \frac{1}{p(p-1)} \sum_{b \mid q-1} b \le - \frac{1}{p} $$
Using the fact that $\sum_{b \mid q-1} b \ge q-1$. So the probability that $p$ is a counterexample is $\ge $

$$ 1- e^{-1/p} \simeq \frac{1}{p} $$

We use this logarithm-product strategy to estimate the probability $Q_x$ of finding a counterexample $\le x$. The probability of not having counterexamples up to $x$ is

$$ 1- Q_x = \prod_{p \le x} \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{p} \right ) \simeq exp(-\sum_{p \le x} \frac{1}{p} )\simeq exp(-\log \log x) = \frac{1}{\log(x)}$$

From which we get $Q_x \simeq 1- \frac{1}{\log x} $. This tends to $1$, so it is almost certain that a counterexample exists. On the other side, it goes to zero very slowly.

**Example.** Suppose you want to be $99\%$ sure to find a counterexample up to $x$. Then
$$\frac{99}{100} \simeq 1- \frac{1}{\log x} \ \ \Leftrightarrow \ \ \ \log x \simeq 100 $$

Which implies $x \simeq e^{100} \simeq 10^{43}$.

P.S. I am missing the case $p=2$, in which the Lifting the Exponent Lemma is slightly different; it should work the same way, though (the only different passage is the last, I which I think it is enough to verify the case $\Phi_{2^n}(x) = x^{2^{n-1}}+1$ :) )

Comment: Interesting stuff, and surely Möbius is a natural approach. But you lost me in Case 1. Why would $p^2\mid f(n)$ imply that $n$ is a double root in $\Bbb{F}_p$? Consider for example $f(x)=x^2-1$. We have $9\mid f(1)$ but the roots of $f(x)$ in $\Bbb{F}_3$ are simple?

Comment: Well... I think you are right. I also thought in the meantime that it Is the only part in which we really use $x=n$; but I only used that $x\le n$, so the argument would show thst $\Phi_n(x) $ is square free for every $x \le n$. This seems weird.

Comment: Also, let me remark that I have tested the case $q^2 \mid p^p-1, p \mid q-1$ for $p, q$ primes up to $10^7$ and there is no counterexample. Seems like a number "can't" gain two factors $q$ in a unique power (which is compatible with LTE intuition in the case $q \mid n-1$)

Comment: I thought better, and I think that in light of the new observations a counterexample can exist. However, with some resonable heuristic assumptions, I think that the counterexample for $p$ should have something like 300 digits, which is completely out of reach with a calculator... I'll add my heuristic soon.

Comment: Looking forward to it. This kind of congruences modulo $q^2$ are, indeed, rare. If they exist at all. Somehow reminds me of the Wieferich situation (also extremely rare).

Comment: It Is very similar, actually. Incidentally, I tried to deduce our problem from a problem about the order of $2$ being $p-1$ modulo $p^2$ , by taking $n=(p-1) /2$ and noticing that $-2$ is the inverse modulo $p$, but I didn't succed to promote $ord_p(2) = ord_p(p-1/2) $ to $p^2$.

Comment: Can you do it under the assumption that $2$ is a primitive root modulo $p^2$? Assuming Artin's conjecture $2$ is primitive for a positive fraction of the primes. And thus highly likely to generate $\Bbb{Z}_{p^2}^*$ for infinitely many primes $p$.

Comment: The heuristic apparently failed in this case. See my counterexample above.

Comment: Nevertheless, I reward your efforts with an upvote.

Comment: Maybe I was misunderstood, but the heuristics suggested that a counterexample exist! Plugging your $p$, you had a 93% chance of getting a counterexample $\le p$. I wasn't enough riskful in considering $90%$ a good chance :) however, I am happy we found the counterexample!! How did you get It?

Comment: Just for the sake of fun, 93% is about the chance of rolling two dices and getting at least 3 as sum. Definitely convenient! XD

Comment: As an acceleration, I used that a prime factor $p\mid \Phi_n(n)$ must satisfy $p\equiv 1\mod n$ and that for a counterexample the order of $n$ modulo $p^2$ must be exactly $n$. This allowed me to check a relatively large range giving only one counterexample.

Comment: So you used my criterion? :D cool!

Answer (score 12):

Checking the pairs $n,p\le 10^6$ , I found one counterexample , namely :

$$283411^2\mid \Phi_{28341}(28341)$$

Comment: I think Mathematica's integer arithmetic can be trusted, and this checks out.

Comment: [partial factorization of the counterexample](http://factordb.com/index.php?query=%2828341%5E28341-1%29*%2828341%5E201-1%29*%2828341%5E6%2B28341%5E3%2B1%29%2F%2828341%5E9447-1%29%2F%2828341%5E603-1%29%2F%2828341%5E282%2B28341%5E141%2B1%29)

Comment: For the record: I have added this as the 55th answer to the "big-list" question [Examples of eventual counterexamples](https://mathoverflow.net/a/381841).

Comment: I hope you are fine with Andrea getting the bounty. In the end I went with the popular vote, which was very close (8 to 7 at decision time). Yours gives more definite information, but users will find both answers useful. Plus, Andrea can use the points but you have a fair amount already. Looking forward to sponsoring similar interesting questions in the future.

Comment: I understand your arguments and I am not someone who cares about $500$ points , in particular for my own question. But I must say that , in principle , I cannot follow the decsision to give a full bounty despite of the close end-result. If you were unsure, you could have shared or weighted the bounty. I do not consider the winning answer to be particular helpful, although I upvoted it for the effort.

Comment: A far better argument would have been that my own answer is "out of contest" because it is strange that a user can receive a bounty for an answer of his own question. If I understood it right, this is actually possible , something the moderators should think about.

Comment: I mean I'd be also ok with the bounty being splitted! As Jyrki pointed out I have not much réputation, so this bounty could bè useful in the future and I thank you for that. However, I don't understand why Peter is not so convinced about my answer, honestly I think that a straight factorization would have been impossible to test for such big numbers, while the criterion I gave is much faster. I also gave the heuristic to such a counterexample to exist. I was wrong, though, in deducing that it would have been way larger; that's definitely on me. Best, Andrea